# Express, ws, websocket, express-ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, rest, express

I'm writing server-side for my project and it requires features websockets provides. I've been searching and found 3 libraries in npm. ws, websocket and express-ws. Can you please explain the difference between them and give the pros and cons for each?

I'm using Express in my project. Is it okay that I'm using REST API and websockets simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the full answer.

if you search from npm, the famous websocket libraries are socket.io and ws. Both of them hit more than 4 millions download per month.

Many people use socket.io because of the rich features, but you may be overwhelming when you are studying it.

ws is my favorite, and many people may consider it as a simple and easy solution. In fact, the express-ws library that you mention is built on top of ws.

I created a library which built on top of ws as well. You can try it out. Super easy to use. It supports both node.js and client-side. Websocket can be created easily, and the library will handle the websocket and reconnect itself when dropped. Check the example folder or run it to see the effect.

[wsm - WebSocket Manager](https://github.com/jefftham/wsm)